# SI-prefix with significant digits but trimming trailing decimal zeros in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, svg, format

```
d3.format('.2s')( 1234 );    // "1.2k"
d3.format('.2s')( 1000 );    // "1.0k"

// want
d3.format('???')( 1234 );    // "1.2k"
d3.format('???')( 1000 );    // "1k",  NOT "1.0k"
```

Possible to use the same `'???'` format to get both wanted strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will handle both cases.

```
d3.format(".2s")(1000).replace('.0', '');//1k
d3.format(".2s")(1234).replace('.0', '');//1.2k
```